# Delay in serial response

Tags: python, linux, serial-port

I'm connecting to a device running on linux using serial port. The issue i'm having is the responses seem to not appear right away. For example instead of getting the prompt (aa@bb:~$) I get it after I send my command. Another example is I have Up Key triggered so that it returns the command history but it won't appear until I hit enter

Here is my code for

```
def checkSerialPort(self):
    global startup_flag, get_DeviceInfo
    if (serialInst.is_open):
        if serialInst.in_waiting:
            pos = str(int(mainWindow.text_box.index("end")[0])-1)+".1"
            # pos = str(int(mainWindow.text_box.index("end")[0])-1)
            packet_byte = serialInst.readline()
            packet_string = packet_byte.decode('utf-8')
            print(packet_string)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: It's probably a problem with the function you're using. Normally, `serialInst.readline()` will not complete until the end of one line (Enter key: carriage return code) is notified.